# Using different arguments for different functions

Tags: c++

I have a class with several different subclasses and I'm using a virtual bool to update all of them from an `std::list`. What I'm wondering, though, is if I can use different arguments for the separate bools, as the subclasses behave differently and I don't want to accommodate all of them by providing useless data.

```
for (std::list<gameobject*>::iterator it = renderobjects.begin(); it != renderobjects.end(); ++it)
{
    if(!(*it)->update(arguments)){cout<<"error";}
}
```

Is there a way I can rewrite the code so that the `update()` function is given the arguments it needs for the specific subclass it's being called with?

Comment: Yikes, a list full of disjoint elements that each point to other disjoint locations in memory. This is really a CPU's worst nightmare. Unless you have a good reason not to, at least make that a vector.

Comment: Are you saying you have a list L of different classes, but all same parent class objects? L = [Class1:Papa, Class2:Papa, Class3:Papa]? Trying to understand this question.

Comment: I have a list containing several objects of different subclasses, all with a common parent. So, class gameobject, then class player : public gameobject, etc.

Comment: So essentially the question is, what is a C++ version of Java's instaceof?

Comment: That's a good way of putting it, but since there are several different subclasses I don't want to run the iterator through tons of ifs.

Comment: Something is going to have to go through a ton of ifs. You can work this into the update(), but at the end of the day you have to check what 'it' is and that's O(n).

Comment: How does the caller known what arguments are required? Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 0):

This hosts some valuable information to help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/50090/

The gist is that you want to do a dynamic_cast and check if it was successful or not.

A simpler alternative is to add a string ClassID to every class or subclass that defines what it is. Then just check for that ClassID string.

```
if (fooObj.classID == "fooClass") { // do something }
```

Comment: I was thinking of using something like that (I have an ID implemented for each subclass anyway for a different purpose), I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing it rather than checking every ID individually.

Comment: Dynamic cast will require checking every ID individually as well :-/.

Comment: Right, that's why I didn't go with that either. I wonder if a switch-case would work any better.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach the problem:

- have overloads of the `update` function that accept different arguments, and/or

  - then you need some way to work out which one to call
- have `update` accept arguments of a type such as `vector<>` or `map<>` that can contain a variable number of logical arguments, but then you have trouble passing the values in a type-safe way, and potential run-time errors when they're missing

You could combine these approaches to lessen the downsides, perhaps:

```
class gameobject
{
    ...

    enum Fields
    {
        ...  
    };

    tyepdef vector<Fields> Fields;
    virtual Fields get_fields_needed() const;
    typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::string, ...> Field_Types;
    virtual bool update(const vector<Field_Types>&);
};

...

for (std::list<gameobject*>::iterator it = renderobjects.begin(); it != renderobjects.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<Fields> needed = (*it)->get_fields_needed;
    vector<Field_Types> fields;
    for (Fields::const_iterator i = needed.begin(); i != needed.end(); ++i)
         switch (*i)
         {
           case Field_A: fields.push_back(Field_Types(a_value)); break;
           case Field_B: fields.push_back(Field_Types(b_value)); break;
           ...
         }
    if (!(*it)->update(fields)) { cerr << "error"; }
}
```

Whether that's "over-engineered" for your purposes will depend on how many functons, parameters, combinations of parameters etc. you have....